Soil Moisture Sensor ADC value is inaccurate
I am planning on making a soil moisture sensor with a capacitive sensor, Thonny ide, micropython, and a raspberry pi pico w, and I followed some online tutorials as I am relatively new to the world of electronics and pcbs, but the ADC values I am getting seem to be very far off. Like when I put the sensor in a dry environment, the ADC value reads 10418 or a value along that line, and the value in a wet environment would garner only slight changes.
Here is the code I used:
from machine import ADC, Pin
import utime
    
    
def get_capacitator_measurements():
    soil_adc = ADC(Pin(26)) # pin for analog values
    while True:
        print("ADC Value is -----> %d" % soil_adc.read_u16())
        utime.sleep(0.5)
        
get_capacitator_measurements()

Here is the result I am getting when it is completely submerged in water and a dry environment:

Here is the image of the hardware:

I researched a bit online and I have already soldered the GND pin to a 1MOhm resistor to the sensor but the result is still the same. I have attached photos of the code I used and the hardware. Would greatly appreciate any insight to solve this issue. Thank you.

Due to parallax I can't see clearly what pins of the pico go into which holes in the proto board. Also I don't see which sensor wires go to which holes, because you only show the ends. In any case, your connections do not look correct, you should double-check. Please provide a better picture.
